# Javascript Object with a variable

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm building a basic game with NSEW navigation.

- Each NSEW button changes the current location's number, 1,2,3,etc.
- Each location has an object that's intended to be associated with it, named loc1,loc2,loc3,etc.
- Each object has a description that needs to be displayed, loc1.desc,  loc2.desc, etc.
- My display function is working, as is my navigation, BUT...

I'm *TRYING* to pass the loc#.desc value corresponding to the correct current location into the function. (This is Javascript, btw). Currently, it looks like this:

`function nextLoc(dir) {
            var newLoc = nav[currentLoc][dir];
            currentLoc=newLoc; 
            displayMessage(loc[currentLoc].desc);}`

I want it to input the current location's number and pass that to the displayMessage function. I've tried it a ton of different ways, but it still does NOT print the description. If I hard code the number (loc2.desc) or just pass currentLoc, it works, returning the correct object description or the currentLoc number. I've also tried:

```
loc+[currentLoc]+.desc
```

Is there a way to do this? I've searched and tried all the different ways to find this but I can't find this specific issue and, at this point, I'm just lost! Any help is greatly appreciated!!

In answer to comments, here's the whole js file:

```
//Location prototype    
function Location(id, desc){
this.id = id;
this.desc = desc;}
//Location objects
var loc2 = new Location(2, "Circus");
var loc1 = new Location (1, "Zoo");
var loc0 = new Location (0,"You entered the park here");

 var currentLoc = 0;
 var EAST  = 0;
 var WEST  = 1;
 var NORTH = 2;
 var nav = [ // E,W,N,S
     /*Current Location*/ 
     /* 0 */ [2,1,4,-1],
     /* 1 */ [0,-1,3,-1],
     /* 2 */ [-1,0,5-1],
     /* 3 */ [4,-1,-1,1],
     /* 4 */ [5,3,-1,0],
     /* 5 */ [-1,4,-1,2],
     ];        
  // Directional Button Event Handlers
 function btnEast_click() {nextLoc(EAST);}
 function btnWest_click() {nextLoc(WEST);}
 function btnNorth_click() {nextLoc(NORTH);}
 function nextLoc(dir) {
    var newLoc = nav[currentLoc][dir];
    currentLoc=newLoc;
    displayMessage(loc[currentLoc].desc);}

 // Utility Function(s)
 function displayMessage(msg) {
    var target = document.getElementById("taMain");
    target.value = msg + "\n\n" + target.value;
 }
```

Comment: HOW are you trying to pass loc#.desc? Can we see more of this?

loc+[currentLoc]+.desc is definitely not going to do anything for you... is loc a string? We need to see more to help you out.

Comment: Can you show us what the `nav` and `loc` objects look like?

Comment: I'm guessing what you're trying to do is dynamically create the properties 'loc1', 'loc2', etc. It would look something like `obj['loc'+num]` where `num` was 1 ,2, or 3, etc.

Comment: I tried `'loc'+[currentLoc]+'desc'` and it's closer. Instead of the actual object description, it returns "loc2.desc", "loc1.desc" as text instead of pulling the text in loc2.desc.

Answer (score 0):

You were quite close to being able to do named-lookups in a map object. Rather than creating a bunch of independent locations (which in a browser, end up as properties of the `window` object, so there was an avenue that I've chosen not to pursue that would've let you use them.

What I'm doing below is creating an object for the static locations. Another approach would be to use notation like this, which would actually result in the same behavior but might be easier to understand what's going on:

```
var locations = [];
locations['loc2'] = new Location(2, "Circus");
locations['loc1'] = new Location(1, "Zoo");
locations['loc0'] = new Location(0, "You entered the park here.");
```

Also workable would be removing the 'loc' prefix on your keys, then you could write things like this:

```
var locations = [];
locations.add = function(id, desc){ locations[id] = new Location(id, desc)}
locations.add(0, "You entered the park here.") 

// and your navigation method looks like this then
function nextLoc(dir){
    var newLoc = nav[currentLoc][dir];
    currentLoc=newLoc;
    displayMessage(locations[currentLoc].desc);
}
```

Another form which resembles what you've done so far

```
var locations = {
   loc2 : new Location(2, "Circus"), 
   loc1 : new Location (1, "Zoo"),
   loc0 : new Location (0,"You entered the park here")
};

 function nextLoc(dir) {
    var newLoc = nav[currentLoc][dir];
    currentLoc="loc"+newLoc;
    displayMessage(locations[currentLoc].desc);}
```